# How can I edit the values of modifiers on multiple objects at the same time?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

When I select multiple objects, an active object is selected automatically which gets the modifiers changes. How can I select multiple objects to edit their modifiers all at once?

Comment: Did you try (CTRL+L) in object mode to link the modifiers applied to the active object to the rest of the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F3 for search bar -> Apply All modifiers.

If you want to make changes to modifiers that replicate to all objects you can use CTRL+L which will copy the modifiers of the active objects accross all the selected ones.

Answer (score 4):

If multiple objects are already using the same modifier, you can modify a value of it, which will be propagated to all selected objects, by holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while changing the value or by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> clicking into a field and entering its value.

Modifying properties of multiple objects simultaneously with <kbd>Alt</kbd> is not restricted to modifiers.